# Trying to get most frequently occuring value from a serialized array

Tags: jquery

I'm wanting to find the most frequently occuring value in a serialized array. From other posts I've got this far but the alert returns "object Object"?

This level of jQuery is way over my head so I have no idea where I'm going wrong. Would anyone please be able to help me out a little?

```
function showValues() {
    var store = $( ":radio" ).serializeArray(); 
    var frequency = {}; 
    var max = 0; 
    var result;   
    for(var v in store) {
            frequency[store[v]]=(frequency[store[v]] || 0)+1;  frequency.
            if(frequency[store[v]] > max) {
                max = frequency[store[v]];  
                result = store[v];          
            }
    }   
    alert(result);
}
```

What have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

The serialized array contains name-value pairs. If you want to access the actual form values, you have to use the `value` property.

```
function showValues() {
  var store = $(":radio").serializeArray();
  var frequency = {};
  var max = 0;
  var result;

  for (var v in store) {
    frequency[store[v].value] = (frequency[store[v].value] || 0) + 1;
    if (frequency[store[v].value] > max) {
      max = frequency[store[v].value];
      result = store[v].value;
    }
  }

  alert(result);
}
```